# DAX - Sum rows with the latest dates across multiple columns

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I am new to PowerPivot / DAX and am analyzing a table named BudgetTable with 5 columns.  When the budgeted amount changes for an Item and Attribute combination, users add a new row to the table with a new record date. In the table below, for example, the 2/1/19, 3/1/19, 4/1/19 and 5/1/19 records are updates of prior Item and Attribute combinations.

```
ID  Item  Attribute   Budget Amount  Record Date
1     A      AA          $1000         1/1/19
2     A      AA          $2000         2/1/19
3     A      BB          $3000         1/1/19
4     A      BB          $4000         3/1/19
5     B      AA          $5000         1/1/19
6     B      AA          $6000         5/1/19
7     B      BB          $7000         1/1/19
8     B      BB          $8000         4/1/19
```

I would like to define a measure (Sum of Budget Amount) that sums up the Budget Amounts using the latest date for each Item and Attribute combination.

I have tried:

```
Sum of Budget Amount:=CALCULATE([BudgetTable], FILTER(BudgetTable, BudgetTable[Record Date]=Max(BudgetTable[Record Date])
```

but, that produces a pivot table that looks like:

```
Item   Attribute   Sum of Budget Amount
 A                        $4000
           AA             $2000
           BB             $4000
 B                        $6000
           AA             $6000
           BB             $8000
```

The expected pivot table would look like:

```
Item     Attribute   Sum of Budget Amount
 A                        $6000
           AA             $2000
           BB             $4000
 B                       $14000
           AA             $6000
           BB             $8000
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create Dimension from your your fact table:

```
      Calendar = CALENDARAUTO()
      ITEM = VALUES(Budget[Item])
      ATTRIBUTE = VALUES(Budget[Attribute])
```

2 - Create your model setting the relationship:

[Modelling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ze8.png)

3 - Create the mesure that answer the question :

```
Total Budget = 
  SUMX(
     'ITEM';
      SUMX(
         'ATTRIBUTE';
          CALCULATE(
             Sum(Budget[Budget Amount]);
             LASTNONBLANK(
                 'Calendar'[Date];
                 COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Budget))
             )
         )
     )
 )
```

4 - Result

[Here you can see the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZP068.png)

Comment: Thank you for the tip to dimensionalize my model.   I can see how that makes things easier.  It seems that your approach presumes that the table is sorted so that the latest dates are at the bottom.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
Measure =
// SUMX iterates the table in its arg1, evaluating the expression in arg2
// for each row of the table.
SUMX (
    // Output of GROUPBY is a two-column table of unique combinations
    GROUPBY (
        'BudgetTable',
        'BudgetTable'[Item],
        'BudgetTable'[Attribute]
    ),
    VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'BudgetTable'[Record Date] ) ) // max date for current row
    RETURN
        CALCULATE (
            'SUM ( 'BudgetTable'[Amount] ),
            'BudgetTable'[Record Date] = MaxDate
        )
)
```

It is a good idea to dimensionalize your model per the response from @JBfreefolks, but it is not necessary for this specific measure.